# Perl increment or decrement, but not both?

Tags: perl, syntax, increment, decrement

```
$a++;     # ok
$a--;     # ok
--$a;     # ok
++$a;     # ok
--$a++;   # syntax error
$a++--;   # syntax error
($a++)--; # syntax error
--$a--;   # syntax error
```

On some of these, I can sort of see why- but on like `--$a--` there is no ambiguity and no precedence conflict. I'm floored Larry didn't let me do that.. (and don't even get me started on the lack of a floor operator!)

Not that I would need or want to- I was just trying to understand more about how these operators worked and discovered that sort of surprising result..

Comment: Probably because there are no sane semantics for `++$a--`..

Comment: `++$a--`: add one to the value stored in $a and return the new value, then subtract one from the value stored in $a.  Hmm, `$a+1` saves you two characters, two writes to memory, and several processor cycles.  Gains in Maintainability don't hurt either...

Comment: Perl comes with a `floor` in POSIX.pm

Comment: It may be difficult to envision practical applications of similar syntax to pedestrian programming, but in my world, where I write Perl that writes more Perl, I could easily run into a case where I might ++ or -- a clause, pre or post. It could be an easier to program it than looking back to see if it had been previously decremented etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Perldoc for auto increment/decrement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) we find:

> "++" and "--" work as in C.

and slightly earlier on the same page

> Perl operators have the following associativity and precedence, listed from highest precedence to lowest. Operators borrowed from C keep the same precedence relationship with each other, even where C's precedence is slightly screwy. (This makes learning Perl easier for C folks.)

Since C returns an *rvalue* in both cases, Perl does the same.  Interestingly, C++ returns a reference to an *lvalue* for pre-increment/decrement thus having different semantics.

Comment: perl also returns an lvalue for pre- (though not one that can be used in a direct assignment)

Comment: @ysth, By your definition, every operator returns an lvalue in Perl. That's a useless definition. It's much more useful to defined "returns an lvalue" as "flagged as returning an lvalue".

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
length($x) = 123;
```

Just like `++(++$a)`, there is no ambiguity, there is no precedence conflict, and it would require absolutely no code to function. The limitation is completely artificial<sup>[1]</sup>, which means code was added specifically to forbid it!

So why is `length($x) = 123;` disallowed? Because disallowing it allows us to catch errors with little or no downside.

```
length($x) = 123;        # XXX Did you mean "length($x) == 123"?
```

How is it disallowed? Using a concept of lvalues. lvalues are values that are allowed to appear on the left of a scalar assignment.

Some operators are deemed to return lvalues.

```
$x = 123;                # $x returns an lvalue
$#a = 123;               # $#a returns an lvalue
substr($s,0,0) = "abc";  # substr returns an lvalue
```

Some arguments are expected to be an lvalue.

```
length($x) = 123;        # XXX LHS of scalar assignment must be an lvalue
++length($x);            # XXX Operand of pre/post-inc/dec must be an lvalue.
```

The pre/post-increment/decrement operators aren't flagged as returning an lvalue. Operators that except an lvalue will not accept them.

```
++$a = 123;              # XXX Did you mean "++$a == 123"?
```

This has the side effect of also preventing `++(++$a)` which would work fine without the lvalue check.

```
$ perl -E'                              ++(      ++$a); say $a;'
Can't modify preincrement (++) in preincrement (++) at -e line 1, near ");"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ perl -E'sub lvalue :lvalue { $_[0] }  ++lvalue(++$a); say $a;'
2
```

Changing `++$a` to return an lvalue would allow `++(++$a)` to work, but it would also allow `++$a = 123` to work. What's more likely? `++$a = 123` was intentional, or `++$a = 123` is a typo for `++$a == 123`?

---

1. The following shows that `length($x) = 123` would work without the lvalue syntax check.

   ```
   $ perl -E'                              say length($x) = 123;'
   Can't modify length in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "123;"
   Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

   $ perl -E'sub lvalue :lvalue { $_[0] }  say lvalue(length($x)) = 123;'
   123
   ```

   The value you see printed is the value of the scalar returned by `length` after it was changed by the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

For example, what do you expect for:

```
$a = 1;
$b = --$a++;   # imaginary syntax
```

I think it will be harder to explain that $b is equals to 0 and $a is 1, isn't it?... In any case, I don´t remember any real example where that syntax would be useful. It's useless and ugly

Comment: I never said it was or practical ; this was specifically a syntactical question. At OSCON, we'd toss around these syntax proposals with Randal, John Orwant and of course the Perl Master MJD himself. I thought some Perl experts at that level cruised SO which is why I asked it here. My apologies.

Comment: Assuming it were possible I'd expect `$a` to return to it's original value and `$b` to hold `$a-1`.

However, as has been pointed out, -- and ++ return the value of the variable, not the variable itself, so applying -- to $a would return the constant 0, to which we would then attempt to apply ++, resulting in an error.